# Translate 3rd-party C# to PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, translate

Working with a recently acquired dll (for working in a .NET sdk) from one of our hardware vendors. They have provided decent documentation with all the classes, methods, etc. But all their examples are in C#. I am not versed in C# and am working on translating everything to PowerShell. I've some progress, but have hit a wall and am looking for some help.

Here's their Example in C#:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Vendor.Components.Flashlight.Sdk.Examples
    {
        class MyApp
        {
            public void Execute()
            {
                var device = new FlashlightController();
                device.Light(FlashlightColor.Green);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's where I am in PowerShell so far (if there's a more eloquent way, feel free to let me know):

```
    ## Vendor DLL path
    $assemblyFlashlight = 'C:\FlashlightDLL\Flashlight.Sdk.dll'
    ## Adding new assembly as a Type and listing members
    $typeFlashLight = Add-Type -Path $assemblyFlashlight -PassThru
    $typeFlashlight

    IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
    -------- -------- ----                                     --------
    True     False    DotfuscatorAttribute                     System.Attribute
    True     False    BusylightController                      System.Object
    True     True     BusylightSoundClip                       System.Enum
    True     True     BusylightVolume                          System.Enum
    True     False    BusylightColor                           System.Object
    False    False    b                                        System.Object
    False    False    c                                        System.Object
    False    False    e                                        System.Object
    False    False    f                                        System.Object
    False    False    d                                        System.Object
    False    False    i                                        System.ValueType
    False    False    a                                        System.ValueType
    False    False    g                                        System.Object
    False    False    h                                        System.ValueType
    False    True     d                                        System.MulticastDelegate
    False    False    b                                        System.ValueType
    False    False    e                                        System.Object
    False    False    c                                        System.Object
    False    False    f                                        System.Object
    False    False    a                                        d
    False    False    a                                        System.Object


    ## Creating objects
    $objController = New-Object $typeFlashLight[1]
    $objSoundClip = New-Object $typeFlashLight[2]
    $objVolume = New-Object $typeFlashLight[3]
    $objColor = New-Object $typeFlashLight[4]
```

The above PowerShell code runs without error and all my $obj variables contain the expected members:

```
    $objColor|Get-Member

    Name          MemberType Definition
    ----          ---------- ----------
    Equals        Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    GetHashCode   Method     int GetHashCode()
    GetType       Method     type GetType()
    ToString      Method     string ToString()
    BlueRgbValue  Property   int BlueRgbValue {get;set;}
    GreenRgbValue Property   int GreenRgbValue {get;set;}
    RedRgbValue   Property   int RedRgbValue {get;set;}
```

So I think I am on the right track. But I can't figure out how to translate certain things like 'IsPublic', 'IsSerial', and my reasearch on 'Dotfuscator' didn't give me anything I could digest.

Answer (score 2):

IsPublic and IsSerial are not properties that you want to implement.  They are properties of System.RuntimeType for which there is one of these associated with every type in .NET.  Try this:

```
$objColor.GetType()
```

As for converting C# to PowerShell, keep in mind that there isn't always a 100% mapping.  That is, in PowerShell you can't create a class or interface much less a type that derives from another type.  In CLI speak, PowerShell is more of a consumer language than a producer language.  Most of the time that isn't a problem for a basic utility library.  But if that library is really a framework that requires you to inherit from their base classes or interfaces, you won't be able to use PowerShell.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. In retrospect, I think asking for a 'conversion' was overstating the need. All I really need is to be able to interact with this api without having to master another language to do so. Could one wrap the existing C# code in PoSh code? Or is the only practical solution to take the time to learn C#?

Comment: If you only need to call APIs then you'll probably be able to do that from PowerShell. Don't worry about Dotfuscator as it should only muck with the name of non-public types and type members.  BTW you should be able to new up the objects by type name e.g. new-object '<fully-qualified-type-name-here>' -arg <array-of-constructor-args-here>.

Comment: So, "If you only need to call APIs then you'll probably be able to do that from PowerShell", eh? Can you point me to a resource that would give me the principles that one would use to go about doing that? I know every API is built differently, but I imagine there are certain 'hooks' that would be common for any .NET-based api?

Comment: Take a look at this blog post: http://mybsinfo.blogspot.com/2007/01/powershell-adventure-chpt2-using-net-in.html  Also, chapter 17 in Windows PowerShell in Depth 2nd Edition covers the topic - http://www.amazon.com/Windows-PowerShell-Action-Second-Edition/dp/1935182137